# Angular 7: change method on input with datalist

Tags: angular, html, typescript, input, angular7

I need an input that call a method only when an option is selected. 
I have a list of Product[] with

```
Id:number 
Name:string
```

For Example: ID: 2 and Name: Coffee. I need to see Coffee in the suggestion list but when I select it the method sent only the ID or the entire object.

I try different solution, using 
**value** or 
**attr.data-value**  with ID of Product in the **option** element and it  doesn’t work: when I select an option, the input field is filled with ID and not with Name

Comment: if you're using *ngFor="let item of Products", you can use [value]="item" or [value]="item.Id" acording you want only the id or the whole object. What has you try?

Answer (score 0):

If you want "Name" only just use 
`<input list="datalist" /> <datalist id="datalist"> <option *ngFor="let prod of listProd" [value]="prod.Name">{{prod.Name}}</option> </datalist>`

This way the "Name" is show in the option box and you get back the "Id" when it's selected. If you want the complete object back then replace Product.Id with just Product and you get back everything

Updated.

Comment: Wrong. I have 

```
<input list="datalist" />
<datalist id="datalist">
  <option *ngFor="let prod of listProd" [value]="prod.id">{{prod.name}}</option>
</datalist>
```
And when list option is open, it show ID  Name (1 Coffee) and when I press on it, input field is filled with "1" not "Coffee"

Comment: Have you then tried changing [value]="prod.id" to [value]="prod.name"? Also remember your names are case sensitive so if you use Id and Name in your object you also have to use the same in the html part.

Comment: With [value] and {{prod.Name}} the string will be duplicated in the dropdown. Datalist is not like select htmlElement. On chrome [value] is displayed always. I try with [attr.data-value]=prod.id but I don't know how to intercept the id in the (change) method from input

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that works for me.
The ng-select element. 
[All is explained here](https://ng-select.github.io/ng-select#/data-sources)
This is the code that I use for my solution

```
<ng-select [items]="listProduct"
             bindLabel="name"
             bindValue="idProduct"
             (change)="onProductSelect($event)">
</ng-select>
```

I use (change) instead of [(ngModel)] because I read that it's better for perfomance. onProductSelect recive entire object selected.